# extracting the first 10KB chunk from a text file and then moving the new file to a different location

Tags: bash, sh

I have all the text files at bigdata/*.txt.The format of this file is languageName-xxx-10MB.txt. I want to perform an operation that would chunk these files from 10MB to the first 10KB recursively and then place the newly formed file at ../smalldata/.The newly formed file should be in the format of languageName-xxx-10KB.txt

I have tried both the operations independently.The first being looping over all the files in the bigdata/ using

```
#!/bin/bash
for entry in bigdata/*
do
echo "$entry"
done
```

I get the output as

```
bigdata/lang1-xxx-10MB.txt
bigdata/lang2-xxx-10MB.txt
.
.
bigdata/langn-xxx-10MB.txt
```

I have also tried using the `head` command that gets me the first 10KB of the files using

```
head -c 10240 lang1-xxx-10MB.txt > ../smalldata/lang1-xxx-10KB.txt
```

I am looking for a way to merge this two tasks iteratively.

Comment: So you know how to do what you want to one file, and you know how to run a command for all files you want to do it to... Where are you stuck?

Comment: @that other guy I am stuck in doing the process Iteratively.I want to lookup all the files in the directory.Perform the head command.Change the names of the files from 10MB to 10KB and then store them in another location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While inside the directory containing your `bigdata` and `smalldata` directories, you can run

```
#!/bin/bash
cd bigdata
for entry in *
do
  head -c 10240 "$entry" > "../smalldata/${entry//10MB/10KB}"
done
```

The `${..}` part is known as [parameter expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064944/bash-shell-parameter-expansion).

Comment: I want to find files in bigdata/* so that I get just the file names. Basically I want to run the script from outside the folder i.e my directory structure is bigdata smalldata script

Comment: I did the same.Smart move!

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash
BIGDATA=bigdata/*
SMALLDATA=smalldata
for entry in $BIGDATA
do
    filename=`basename $entry`
    newname=$(echo $filename | awk -F '-' '{print $1 "-" $2 "-10KB.txt"}')
    head -c 1 $entry > $SMALLDATA/$newname
done
```